# Conceptual - how to write a mini-app in jQuery, including data storage in the browser?

Tags: jquery

I'm not going to get specific here with code, because I don't feel like people on stackoverflow.com should be doing my job for me. But I've got a general concept I'm going to be prototyping soon and I'd like to know what the best way to approach it is.

Basically, I will be writing a mini-app in jQuery that will allow a user to select items from a list, and have those items memorized indefinitely. On top of that, I'll offer a "preferences" option that will allow a user to select various options via checkboxes and pulldowns, and all of that should be stored as well. When I say this data is stored/memorized, I mean per session of course, and even after the browser is closed. This is 100% front-end, we have no access to the back-end whatsoever.

One more thing: this list of items the user is selecting (let's say they're choosing office numbers from a huge list) should be easily accessible to me from some sort of data structure. I COULD just use jQuery to pull it from an LI tag or something, but that seems hacky. Rather I'd like to be able to have a data structure that I could store these things in and easily pull out, instead of traversing through HTML to get to what the user has selected.

Thoughts?

EDIT: Yes, we're talking small storage here, like storing very small numbers or Y/N values. Nothing major. An array of number values, probably no bigger than 20-30 items in the array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the only option left for you is

cookies

You can play around with Session cookies and Persistent Cookies

Answer (score 1):

The [AmplifyJS](http://amplifyjs.com/) jQuery plugin provides everything you're looking for.  It has a `Store` API which provides full-featured persistent client-side data storage: http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/

This should simplify cross-browser (including mobile) support for you, and will use the best (fastest) persistence method available to the user's browser.

In Amplify, cookies are 'least-preferred'.  They're supported, but this is what they have to say about them:

> Support for cookies is available as a convenience. Cookies will never automatically become the default storage type because of the bandwidth and performance overhead incurred for all requests.

**Aside:**
HTML5 [is here](http://html5boilerplate.com/), [it's awesome](http://www.html5rocks.com/), and you should [use its features](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) when you can.  Abstractions like AmplifyJS make this very easy, with transparent fallbacks.  [Use polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) for laggards with old browsers.

Comment: where does the data gets stored??

Comment: @kobe: See the page, there's a preference list based on browser-availability. [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html) is used if available.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, if each of these items is small (less than 4KB, I believe is the limit) I'd suggest just using the jQuery cookies plugin to store them. As far as I can tell (someone correct me if I'm wrong) there's no limit to how many cookies you can store, so just give each one an appropriate naming structure and stash JSON in the cookie value.

EDIT: yes, you could use localstorage or HTML5-whatever or some other such storage technique, but the cookies one is guaranteed to work everywhere without special permissions/settings/cooperation. If they flush their cookies they'll get rid of them, but that should be fine.